# How do you unlock special characters in Soul Calibur 5?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

Besides the unlockable DLC character Dampierre, there are quite a few "?" selections in the character menu left for additional characters.

Who are these characters and how do you unlock them? (Most likely spoilers in the answer, I know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a list of the characters and the unlock conditions: 
[HERE](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2012/01/31/how-to-unlock-all-soul-calibur-5-characters-xbox-360-ps3.htm)

Notice some have multiple unlock methods, some of which are easier than others.

Also here is a list of them all for quick reference:

- Special Character 1

  > • Algol
  >  Method 1: After completing Story Mode, the Legendary Souls Mode will be unlocked. Defeat him in Legendary Souls Mode and then successfully complete the mode to unlock Algol.
  >  Method 2: Defeat him in Quick Battle as the opponents Teramos (C2-C4 Rank) or Minami Naikos (A2 Rank) to unlock Algol.
  >  Method 3: Defeat him in Arcade Mode with any character.
  >  Method 4: You can also reach Player Level 31 to unlock Algol.
- Special Character 2

  > • Alpha Patroklos
  >  Successfully complete Story Mode with any character.
- Special Character 3

  > • Dampierre
  >  Method 1: Purchase him before release as a Best Buy pre-order in America.
  >  Method 2: Buy him during launch as part of the Collector's Edition in Europe.
  >  Method 3: Other than that you'll have to wait to get Lord Geo Dampierre as future character DLC.
- Special Character 4

  > • Edge Master
  >  Successfully complete Story Mode with any character.
- Special Character 5

  > • Elysium
  >  Successfully complete Story Mode with any character.
- Special Character 6

  > • Kilik
  >  Method 1: Defeat him in Legendary Souls Mode and then successfully complete the mode.
  >  Method 2: Defeat him in Arcade Mode with any character, but make sure to choose the Asia route.
  >  Method 3: You can also reach Player Level 11 to unlock Kilik.
  >  Method 4: You can defeat him in Quick Battle as the opponent “Chaos” with the title “Red Lotus” (A2 Rank) to unlock Kilik. – Two gamers have confirmed that before the match Kilik was locked and after beating “Chaos” he was unlocked.
- Special Character 7

  > • Pyrrha Omega
  >  Successfully complete Story Mode with any character.

There is also several unlockables for Character Creation and Stages which can be unlocked in Story Mode and Quick Match.

Comment: I would suggest adding those characters/methods to this post in case the link ever goes dead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm at work at the moment. I will doctor it up when I get home.

Comment: I was playing through last night and was able to unlock two of the characters via story mode without actually completing it. Possible that the info above is not fully fleshed out as the game is still new.

Comment: Yeah, methods are being added to the site as they are uncovered. I will try to keep up with them on here to ensure the answer is accurate.

Comment: Will mark as accepted for now, regardless, as this is fairly accurate.